# How to Set the title of a button in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar

HI I have a `UITableView` and I have data in my array, i have `search` functionality also here. this is a menu type thing. There are different dishes and user can search any dish, on the left side here is a text Field and its text is 0, when user search some dish then type some other digit in it then how to save that input in the right place, Because at that time its its cell `index` will be different than original. You can see this picture of my `UITableView`
[image]

I know this is a problem of logic but please help me I'm stuck here.

Comment: You'll need to post the relevant bits of code to get reasonable help with this question.

Comment: If I understand it right, you would need to set up an array and reload the data to set the right value for the buttons...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

`[button setTitle:@"title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: problem is that when some user search something then its index is changed

Answer (score 0):

1. At first take a NSMutableArray

**.h file**

NSMutableArray *searchDataArray;

Now declare its property and synthesize it in your .m file

2.In your `-(void)viewDidLoad` alloc your search array and retain it.

1. [I am thinking that you can set searchbar and can call the search delegate]..so in

   ```
    - (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
   [sBar resignFirstResponder];
         searching = YES; //A boolean for searching condition
   [searchData removeAllObjects];
   NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;

   // record is a  mutable array containing the  cell text
   int count = [records count];
   for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
   for(int j=0;j<6;j++){

       //finding the cell strings for checking
       recordsstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[records objectAtIndex:i];
       //Matching string of table and search string


       //case sensitivity checking
       NSString *mainString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[recordsstr lowercaseString]];
       NSString *searchString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[searchText lowercaseString]];
       NSLog(@"main String:  %@ and search string:  %@ ",mainString,searchString);
       NSLog(@"main string lenght: %d and search String lenght: %d",[mainString length],[searchString length]);
       if([mainString isEqualToString:searchString] || [mainString rangeOfString:searchString].location != NSNotFound){
           [searchData addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
           NSLog(@"indext after matching: %d",i);
           NSLog(@"number of date in searchdata array after matching: %d",[searchData count]);
           break;
       }
       recordsstr = nil;
   }
    }
   ```

In this code i am matching the cell text and search text. After finding the cell text taking array of cell index.

now when search is complete then reload your your tableview `[tableview reloadData]`

Now in `cellForRowAtIndex`  check that

```
if(searching == YES){
for(int i = 0; i<[searchData count]; i++){
  if(indexPath.row is equal to [searchData objectAtIndex:i])
   {
  //change your text field
   }
 }
 else{
  //Without searching code
   }
```

May be it will help you.If any problem knock me.